# Can't understand Ember + Node auth

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express

I've been using ember, node, express since 2 months ago.

I've developed an small app, now it's time to add user auth to it but I can't figure out how to do this.

There are a few questions I have:

1.- In SPA apps, where there's only *index.html*, I include all *.js* ember files. So, the user could be able to see all the app logic without auth?. How can I add the libs only when the user has been auth?

2.- What's the *right way* to auth in ember? I haven't seen a solution in official documentation.

3.- How the frontend communicates with the backend, what's the logic here? It's in every route?

Also I'm looking for an example or tutorial.

Thanks you!

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth. It's really nice. You can also find some examples there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these videos target exactly your question

http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1
 http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2

just to mention a great resource for ember tutorials http://emberwatch.com/ - it contains screencasts, books, talks.. articles - all you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing bad about "seeing logic", you are protecting data, not code. Still, if you really want to protect your code, you can create a separate login page and require authentication for every other resource (app html, styles, scripts, etc.). But protecting EVERY resource of your app means that you can't delegate handling static files to nginx or cdn or whatnot. So, think carefully.
2. There are to approaches: embedded authentication and separate login page. For the first one you can use https://github.com/Vestorly/torii or https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth. If you decide to go with the second, you can just use authentication provided by your backend (passport.js, etc) and redirect to login page on failures.
3. Nothing special, you just write your `model` methods and handle possible authorisation errors. You might also want to have a `user` object around to use in your template and route logic.